# Review beta -- skip review vs. vote not to close

Tags: support, vote-to-close, review-page

I've now been using this new review tool (which is great, btw) for a couple of days, and I was wondering what is the difference between not acting on a vote to close, and voting for not to close?

Can those votes for not to close be seen somewhere, or do they affect the outcome somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference between "not acting on a close vote" and voting to "Leave Open" a question. Not acting (or choosing "Skip")

[image]

removes the post in question from *your* review list, while voting to "Leave Open" has an impact on the review list displayed for other users (read further).

You are able to view the previously reviewed close-votes by clicking on the "history" tab under [Close Votes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/close/history):

[image]

In terms of the difference between voting to "Leave Open", the following is taken from [How about a "Vote not to close" option to counter the "Vote to close"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/168244):

> - Voting against closing does not override anyone's close vote. However, a sufficient number of "Do Not Close" responses (currently 3) will kick the question out of the review queue and start aging the close votes - regardless of how many views the question has had.
> - If the question is closed, "Do Not Close" votes do not translate into re-open votes. However, [it may be used] to prioritize items in the Reopen Queue [..].

Comment: +1  Just to note that to see the list with votes from others you need sufficient reputation; otherwise you only see your own actions.